# Raspberry Pi Live Streaming using Picam [Audio+Video]

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, audio, video

I am currently using [picam](https://github.com/iizukanao/picam) software to stream audio and video from Raspberry Pi using a NOIR camera and a microphone. 
One way audio and video is working fine.
I need a two way audio connection but picam only establishes one way .
Any ideas on how to establish two way audio without disturbing the video streaming that is happening?

Comment: It's not particularly normal for audio streams to run in [duplex mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)). The simplest approach is to set up a brand new audio stream originating from the machine currently receiving your audio/video stream. If you've already got a working picam command string it shouldn't be too complicated to yank bits out of it for running audio only.

Comment: Thanks.Yeah it looks like simplest set up is to start a new stream from the machine currently receive audio.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to live stream audio from a transmitter to a receiver, then you can use avtools. You can also use avtools to stream your video+audio.

The simplest approach is to use rtp (real time protocol).
One example is to use ffmpeg or avconv like so ...

First install avtools from the command line (open a terminal and type the following) :

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Next, we have to create the rtp stream on the transmitter, which needs to know the receiver's IP address so that it can blindly stream audio data to it.

```
avconv -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i hw:0,0 -acodec mp2 -f rtp rtp://targetIP:port
```

Here the target IP is the static IP of the receiver. You could use anything reasonable for the port, such as 1234.

To playback you need to use a player, such as VLC or other. Here is an example using avplay :

```
avplay -i rtp://127.0.0.1:port
```

So for example if your receiver has the IP address 192.168.0.10 then you would use this on the transmitter :

```
avconv -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i hw:0,0 -acodec mp2 -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.10:1234
```

Then on the receiver you would use :

```
avplay -i rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```